# Pclint-plus output generation

Tags: pc-lint, sca

I am using 14-days evaluation of PC-lint plus on my linux machine. I can see option to generate output in XML, JSON, CSV, and plain.  Can anyone tell how to generate output in log format.

I tried searching in help menu but couldn't find.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.